How to sort the lines by numbers inside square brackets?
I have lines in a file like:
abc/def/ghi[4]
abc/foo/bar[7]
ghi/jkl/lmn[5]

I want to sort the lines based on the numbers inside square bracket.
I tried :sort n /\[\d\+\]$/ but it's not working as expected.

Reading :help :sort and scrolling a bit down, we find (emphasis mine):

When /{pattern}/ is specified and there is no [r] flag
the text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so that
you sort on what comes after the match.

You're effectively skipping the digit with your pattern.
As there are no digits in your example except those you want to sort by, just
:sort n

will work fine.
To preserve the spirit of your command, you can also tweak your pattern to not include the digit. Either of the following two commands will do that:
:sort n /\[/
:sort n /\[\ze\d\+\]$/

The \ze atom will end the match, see :help /\ze.

somehow the :sort n /\[/  is working for me. the simple :sort n or matching the exact number by :sort n /\[\ze\d\+\]$/ is not working.

@flash this may be caused by the features available in your specific Vim version. I tested this to work with Vim 9.1 on Debian and Windows. The answer is probably found in the output of :version. You may also ask a new question.

You can do:
:sort n r /\[\d\+\]$/

Where:

The r flag is used the sort will only consider the fraction of the text that match the pattern.
The n flag is used to sort using the numeric order instead of the alphanumeric order (thanks to @Friedrich to highlight this)

More information with :help sort

@Friedrich I think that's been addressed by adding n

@D.BenKnoble oh yes, I missed half the edit :-)
